# fb comments disappeared as my page is changed from HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, https

I have a website that was served over HTTP, now it is forced HTTPS. The issue is that the FB Comments disappeared (change of protocol http->https).
Does anyone know of a method to move them to the new URL?

Thanks!

Comment: You’ll need to set the old URL as `og:url` value, and have that still available for the scraper to fetch the relevant OG meta data from. (So if you are automatically redirecting from the HTTP to the HTTPS version, you will need to make an exemption for the scraper.)

Comment: It seems the exception is not needed at all for the FB scraper.